# Are preprocessor-based feature switches necessary in C++ libraries?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, preprocessor

I have been looking at some mature C++ projects and I have noticed a pattern where preprocessor flags are used to enable features at compile-time.

For example:

```
#ifdef MY_WIDGET
Widget createMyWidget() {
    // etc... 
}
#endif
```

Then elsewhere in the code:

```
#ifdef MY_WIDGET
widgets.push_back(createMyWidget());
// etc... 
#endif
```

To me this seems unnecessary since we can employ a strategy pattern, either using inheritance or `std::function`.

Currently the user's application might look like this (where the library has been compiled with `-DMY_WIDGET`):

```
#include <library/startApp.hpp>

int main() {
  startApp(); // createMyWidget will be called by the library
  return 0;
}
```

But instead, we could redesign the library so that the user can write this:

```
#include <library/startApp.hpp>
#include <my-widget-plugin/createMyWidget.hpp>

int main() {
  const std::vector<Widget> widgets = { createMyWidget() };
  startApp(widgets);
  return 0;
}
```

Now the library does not have any compilation switches, which makes the build much simpler, but we can still extend the functionality of the library. This also prevents potential confusion in the case where someone compiles a library without a feature but then tries to use that feature mistakenly.

Appropriate use of `const` allows the compiled binary to be as efficient in either case. If the widgets should be instantiated lazily, we can pass a vector of factories.

Are preprocessor-based feature switches simply a less controlled version of the strategy pattern?

Comment: There has to be a template solution to keep the widget selection at compile-time with a syntax like `startApp<widget1Type, widget2Type, ...>()` or `startApp<widgetEnum::widget1, widgetEnum::widget2, ...>();` if your your widgets are not types or not always available (I can write it if you want)

Comment: Compile-time switches for libraries exist for the same reasons you can (compile-time) configure a linux kernel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main difference is at which time the choice is made.

Precompiler flags are choices you do at compilation time before you even launch your program once, you can then have multiple versions of the program each doing specifically something and nothing more, which cannot be beaten performance wise by any other alternative which applies at a later time.

Then we have:

> The strategy pattern (also known as the policy pattern) is a behavioural software design pattern that enables an algorithm's behaviour to be selected at runtime.
>
> *Wikipedia*

So in its most minimal form there is one branching at runtime, most likely in the form of function pointers. I agree that it is a minimal overhead, but it is an unnecessary one.
The second most notable difference is semantic, since one occurs at compilation time and the other at runtime the conveyed intention is not the same, in the first case you're basically telling people that you have features that you can activate or not for your program, on the second case you're telling people that you have multiple ways of dealing with something and that one can be chosen instead of the others.

---

All in all, if you consider the differences as minor ones, you can go for the one that feels the more confortable as each choice has its small flaws (macro defines have crude preprocessor behaviour and adds a new language level, strategy patterns have unnecessary overhead etc.), but if both are fine for you then use defines when you can choose at compilation time and use strategy to be able to choose at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

A strategy pattern is by definition a run-time algorithm. On the otherhand, Preprocessor features are compile-time. This means, they're resolved while you compile, and after compilation, they don't exist anymore. I'm not sure you're aware of that, but I'd say you are. So your question reduces to: Why would I need preprocessor features at compile-time?

Well, beside the obvious diversity justification, consider a situation where your strategy pattern involves two different libraries. Now, if you use a preprocessor command, you don't have to link to the branch that your program doesn't need. If you use a strategy pattern, *you have to link everything!* Linking to stuff you don't need is just bad-style. It might also be not viable for various reasons (as mentioned by Sebastian in the comments, due to platform or license or other limitations).

Comment: Or plain impossible, if the library isn't available (platform restrictions, license restrictions, ...)

Comment: @SebastianRedl Added these.